# SQL - Proper Decimal Data Type Syntax

Tags: sql, database, decimal, addition

I am trying to add a column to an existing table in a query. I do not have much experience with adding new data to tables, so I am not sure what I have wrong in my current query.

I want to create a new column, and populate it with the product of two separate columns. The data type desired is DECIMAL but I cannot get it to work. Here is my query:

```
ALTER TABLE PPCSTSTR_SQL
ADD vac_var [DECIMAL(16, 6)]

UPDATE PPCSTSTR_SQL
SET    PPCSTSTR_SQL.vac_var = ( PPCSTSTR_SQL.vac_fctr * PPCSTSTR_SQL.vac_rate )

SELECT PPCSTSTR_SQL.*
FROM   PPCSTSTR_SQL
```

I keep getting an error saying: UpdateDisplay: Error getting view data:ReturnValues :Column, parameter, or variable #41: Cannot find data type DECIMAL(16,6).

I have also tried:

```
ADD vac_var DECIMAL(16, 6) //Without the brackets
ADD vac_var [decimal(16, 6)] //Lowercase
```

To my knowledge, this is the correct syntax for creating a new column with a decimal value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What database software are you using?

Comment: @DStanley It is a program called Agility Design Studio by WiSys. I believe it uses T-SQL.

Comment: @Jabo13 I mean the back-end database - SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, etc.  The syntax can be slightly different depending on the server software.

Comment: @DStanley I believe it to be SQL Server, but I honestly have limited knowledge to distinguish the difference.

Comment: Then `ADD vac_var DECIMAL(16, 6)` should work - do you get the _same_ error or a different error?

Comment: @DStanley different error. It reads: UpdateDisplay:Error getting view data: ReturnValues: Invalid column name 'vac_new'. I have tried a number of different column names and none have worked.

Comment: Yeah it helps to read those error messages :).  Not sure why it doesn't like `vac_var` - it's a valid column name in SQL server.  Are there other columns with underscores?  Is there an existing column by that name?

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

`ALTER TABLE tableName
ADD vac_var DECIMAL(16, 6)`